# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/jpeg-exif/lib'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When building a react app on production getting Error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/jpeg-exif/lib'`

Node Version
`Node version 18`

Running command in Docker Production
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
`npm run build`

package.json file

```
"name": "dcts-client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": "ecommerce",
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"@hookform/error-message": "^2.0.0",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.2",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0",
"@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.0.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"card-validator": "^8.1.1",
"cross-domain-storage": "^2.0.7",
"dayjs": "^1.11.5",
"env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
"js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
"lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
"payment": "^2.4.6",
"query-string": "^7.1.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
"react-confirm-alert": "^3.0.6",
"react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
"react-csv": "^2.2.2",
"react-data-table-component": "^7.5.3",
"react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.36.1",
"react-input-range": "^1.3.0",
"react-medium-image-zoom": "^5.0.2",
"react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"react-select": "^5.5.9",
"react-slick": "^0.29.0",
"react-to-print": "^2.14.8",
"react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
"simplebar-react": "^2.4.1",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"styled-components": "^5.3.6",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"build:production": "set REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL=/api && set REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_REDIRECT_URL=http://alb-dct-prd-1561780064.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/ && react-scripts build",
"build:testing": "export REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL=/api REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_REDIRECT_URL=http://dctalb-1569668697.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/ && react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

docker File

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ecommerce

ARG PAYTRACE_URL

ARG REDIRECT_URL

COPY ./DCT-ECOMMERCE/package.json ./

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY ./DCT-ECOMMERCE .

RUN sed -i "s/protect.sandbox.paytrace.com/${PAYTRACE_URL}/g" /usr/src/app/ecommerce/public/index.html

RUN export REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL=/ecomm-api REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_REDIRECT_URL=${REDIRECT_URL} && npm run build -- --profile

FROM nginx:1.24.0-alpine

COPY ./ngnix/nginx-default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
COPY --from=build-ecommerce /usr/src/app/ecommerce/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/ecommerce

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Unexpected behavior

[image]

Comment: Environment variables should be set using the **ENV** instruction, not the **export** command, since export is a shell used to define environment variables in a shell session, but it doesn't work in a *Dockerfile*. ```ENV REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL=/ecomm-api``` and 
```ENV REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_REDIRECT_URL=${REDIRECT_URL}```. Lastly, do ```RUN npm run build -- --profile```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, for me its because @react-pdf/renderer
So i'm uninstalling @react-pdf/renderer, and then add again manually
in package.json

```
"dependencies": {

  "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.1.9",
},
```

then go to package-lock.json and add this

```
    "node_modules/@react-pdf/fns": {
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/fns/-/fns-2.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-/vgecczzFYBQFkgUupH+sxXhLWQtBwdwCgweyh25XOlR4NZuaMD/UVUDl4loFHhRQqDMQq37lkTcchh7zzW6ug==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/font": {
  "version": "2.3.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/font/-/font-2.3.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-ICvVH0GW3kgocxVfE0mFY3EcnAoxRolkOfhPCfLu8mRbwJaHRiKX5+8SRKbPADZNdHrF9ngt4LpUxThy+bdZXg==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/types": "^2.3.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "fontkit": "^2.0.2",
    "is-url": "^1.2.4"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/image": {
  "version": "2.2.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/image/-/image-2.2.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-f0+cEP6pSBmk8eS/wP2tMsJcv2c7xjzca6cr1kwcapr1nzkPrh6fMdEeFl6kR2/HlJK/JoHo+xxlzRiQ8V2lrw==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/png-js": "^2.2.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/layout": {
  "version": "3.6.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/layout/-/layout-3.6.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-xrcVWxtXpobW0iqTd8OmMCVMmeGUM46PYq7B1MGR1fI1QG/EKe4HzFdhSdd0werZYj+t1TRC8+tVSX5POs5SYA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/fns": "2.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/image": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "^3.0.2",
    "@react-pdf/primitives": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-pdf/stylesheet": "^4.1.5",
    "@react-pdf/textkit": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-pdf/types": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-pdf/yoga": "^4.1.2",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "emoji-regex": "^10.2.1",
    "queue": "^6.0.1"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/node_modules/emoji-regex": {
  "version": "10.2.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/emoji-regex/-/emoji-regex-10.2.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-97g6QgOk8zlDRdgq1WxwgTMgEWGVAQvB5Fdpgc1MkNy56la5SKP9GsMXKDOdqwn90/41a8yPwIGk1Y6WVbeMQA=="
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/pdfkit": {
  "version": "3.0.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/pdfkit/-/pdfkit-3.0.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-+m5rwNCwyEH6lmnZWpsQJvdqb6YaCCR0nMWrc/KKDwznuPMrGmGWyNxqCja+bQPORcHZyl6Cd/iFL0glyB3QGw==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/png-js": "^2.2.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "fontkit": "^2.0.2",
    "vite-compatible-readable-stream": "^3.6.1"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/png-js": {
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/png-js/-/png-js-2.2.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-csZU5lfNW73tq7s7zB/1rWXGro+Z9cQhxtsXwxS418TSszHUiM6PwddouiKJxdGhbVLjRIcuuFVa0aR5cDOC6w==",
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/primitives": {
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/primitives/-/primitives-3.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-0HGcknrLNwyhxe+SZCBL29JY4M85mXKdvTZE9uhjNbADGgTc8wVnkc5+e4S/lDvugbVISXyuIhZnYwtK9eDnyQ=="
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/render": {
  "version": "3.2.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/render/-/render-3.2.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-lnef097Dx2vHKpY9OHHNmV+nsG5vpd33h76tCzdlbijj+TyVm1j7ZQ5qadGq1uMOFAU6lp0hEo7VoDk7XnjmFw==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/fns": "2.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/primitives": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-pdf/textkit": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-pdf/types": "^2.3.1",
    "abs-svg-path": "^0.1.1",
    "color-string": "^1.5.3",
    "normalize-svg-path": "^1.1.0",
    "parse-svg-path": "^0.1.2",
    "svg-arc-to-cubic-bezier": "^3.2.0"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer": {
  "version": "3.1.9",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/renderer/-/renderer-3.1.9.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-kfEH7O+Jy7aihbUqrT9Ej1gx8/twRWvFMfHlACr29QsN+s+w0XzWpHCvbjkinVFABYcvsenluiirik6mf4qwRQ==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/font": "^2.3.4",
    "@react-pdf/layout": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "^3.0.2",
    "@react-pdf/primitives": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-pdf/render": "^3.2.4",
    "@react-pdf/types": "^2.3.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "queue": "^6.0.1",
    "scheduler": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/node_modules/scheduler": {
  "version": "0.17.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler/-/scheduler-0.17.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-7rro8Io3tnCPuY4la/NuI5F2yfESpnfZyT6TtkXnSWVkcu0BCDJ+8gk5ozUaFaxpIyNuWAPXrH0yFcSi28fnDA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/stylesheet": {
  "version": "4.1.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/stylesheet/-/stylesheet-4.1.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-8sP+4KD3cAfBEsZBQeJC7GUC0vkCLiAc6kZaGX0dXaBR3nZO2TaCD8+ZuezokZi+ARp/yvWJqR2vIX8ra7X1xA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/fns": "2.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/types": "^2.3.1",
    "color-string": "^1.5.3",
    "hsl-to-hex": "^1.0.0",
    "media-engine": "^1.0.3",
    "postcss-value-parser": "^4.1.0"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/textkit": {
  "version": "4.2.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/textkit/-/textkit-4.2.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-R90pEOW6NdhUx4p99iROvKmwB06IRYdXMhh0QcmUeoPOLe64ZdMfs3LZliNUWgI5fCmq71J+nv868i/EakFPDg==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-pdf/fns": "2.0.1",
    "hyphen": "^1.6.4",
    "unicode-properties": "^1.4.1"
  }
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/types": {
  "version": "2.3.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/types/-/types-2.3.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-FiwAsNp2oQ2W39xAU1PCjY6YNjEuypQykEA6VMz4WZ4ERvyOBB4M5B8063lA8YYBcjYB8xQOa9og4UH1eqMbgg=="
},
"node_modules/@react-pdf/yoga": {
  "version": "4.1.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-pdf/yoga/-/yoga-4.1.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-OlMZkFrJDj4GyKZ70thiObwwPVZ52B7mlPyfzwa+sgwsioqHXg9nMWOO+7SQFNUbbOGagMUu0bCuTv+iXYZuaQ==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13"
  }
},
```

then on terminal

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Legit. Working on npm! Although only tried in a new react project.
But how do you do this on pnpm.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to an internal dependency, not to the `@react-pdf/renderer` package itself. So even downgrading it won't solve it because it's from a minor version and due to ranged versioning, package managers will automatically install the latest minor and patch version of the related internal dependency.
Being fixed. See the comments of the main maintainer about the issue :
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2541#issuecomment-1903877355
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2535#issuecomment-1907093794

For the time being here are some workarounds:

- Yarn

```
// package.json

"resolutions": {
    "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.3",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.4"
 }
```

- Pnpm

```
// package.json

"pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
        "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.3",
        "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.4"
        }
},
```

- Npm

```
// package.json

"overrides": {
    "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.3",
    "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.4"
},
```

Comment: It worked on my project using Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, **"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/jpeg-exif/lib'"**, and your provided **package.json**, it seems you have a FE project designed for browser environments. The error indicates that **jpeg-exif** is trying to use **Node.js**'s `fs` module, which isn't available in browsers.

To resolve this, consider adding a `browser: { fs: false }` setting in your **package.json**. This tells the bundler (like **Webpack** or **Browserify**) to ignore `fs` module references for browser builds. Add this to your **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "dcts-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "ecommerce",
  "dependencies": {
    // ... your dependencies
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using a build tool like **Webpack** in **react-scripts**, modify its configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other configuration settings ...

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false // This line is added to handle 'fs' module for browser
    }
  }
};
```

After these changes, rebuild your project to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: after adding browser: { "fs": false } in a package.json still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upload `package-lock.json` or using `npm config set package-lock false`, you can try this.

I think is because of inside your `@react-pdf/renderer` package.json
dependencies is using `^x.x.x` in `@react-pdf/pdfkit` and `@react-pdf/image` (You can check by package-lock.json), so the version is not same as before.
Try add `"@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.0"` and `"@react-pdf/image": "2.3.0"` in your package.json and remove node_modules to reinstall. (You might check the version of `@react-pdf/image` and `@react-pdf/pdfkit` have no `jpeg-exif` in their package.json)

And use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered to this issue as well. After i checked `yarn.lock` i saw that dependencies of `@react-pdf/renderer@3.1.5` were automatically updated
and had `jpeg-exif` as their dependency (wasn't before) that caused this error. To resolve this issue, I added the previous versions to the `package.json` file using the as below, which allowed me to override their versions with the previous stable version.

-Yarn

```
// package.json
    {
        "dependencies": {
            // ... your dependencies
        },
        "resolutions": {
            "@react-pdf/layout": "3.6.2",
            "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.2",
            "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.1"
        },
      ...
    }
```

-Npm

```
// package.json
    {
        "dependencies": {
            // ... your dependencies
        },
        "overrides": {
            "@react-pdf/layout": "3.6.2",
            "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.2",
            "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.1"
        },
      ...
    }
```

-Pnpm

```
// package.json
    {
        "dependencies": {
            // ... your dependencies
        },
        "pnpm": {
            "overrides": {
               "@react-pdf/layout": "3.6.2",
               "@react-pdf/pdfkit": "3.0.2",
               "@react-pdf/image": "2.2.1"
             }
        },
      ...
    }
```

then after modifying `package.json` rebuild your `Dockerfile` or Pipeline. WORKED FOR ME, hope it resolves your issue.